# How do I email a clinic to book a consultation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to email a clinic to book a consultation about some cosmetic problem I've been dealing with.

Can I say

> I'd like to consult about ...(some cosmetic problem)

Is this the right way to use "consult"?
And does this automatically imply that I will come in person? If not, how should I specify that I want to come in person?

Comment: Typically, it's the person who's the expert in a subject who does the consulting. The person who is *getting* advice is simply present at *a* consult (or consultation). So, it would be strange to hear you say that you want to consult about something when you don't know anything about it yourself. Rather, I would expect to hear something like *Is the doctor free to consult* ***with me*** (at some time)? Or you might say that you need to consult *the doctor* about about something. But I find it odd to hear just *I'd like to consult about*.

Answer (score 2):

While "consult" doesn't always imply "in person", most consultations with doctors are done in person, as the doctor will need to see you to diagnose your problem.

If you want to remove any possible ambiguity you can just add "in person"

> I'd like to consult about (issue) in person....

Or you can ask for "an appointment to see"

> I'd like an appointment to see a doctor regarding (issue).